# There you have it again?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

I wonder if no one has asked it simply because it is so obvious, but I really can't grasp the exact meaning of **there you have it** (*again*). I occasionally infer it from the context but not every single time.

Here are some examples:

> 1 **There you have it again:** a baseless assumption that some undefined external “force” has a mind of its own, and the faint but menacing suggestion that anyone who disagrees is in some fashion opposed to the holy or paternal will.
>
> 2 **There you have it again.** He’s realising again how deeply he cares about her and he doesn’t know what to do with these feelings. He’s lost her twice and he fears to lose her again that’s why he’s afraid to acknowledge that he does feel something for her.
>
> 3 **There you have it again** – the same company, the same city and a very similar incidence.
>
> 4 If you missed the news, **there you have it again.**

Oxford Learner's Dictionaries state that:

**So, there you have it** means ***that's how it all started***.

Can I assume that the above phrase (without *again*) applies to all the examples I've given?

Thank you.

Comment: "There you have it" is a colloquial English expression people use, often at the end of a story or explanation, to mean, "That explains things." I have never heard of it used as in any of the examples, nor have I ever heard it with "again" at the end.

Comment: @GermaneJackson - Thank you. I've made a search through Internet and found these examples. One of them -the first one- is by Christopher Hitchens. I hope there will be someone who will recognize the phrase :)

Comment: This use of *There you have it* is a "summing up, rounding off" statement - where "it" refers to the substance of whatever was previously being talked about. Arguably it's somewhat more "final, conclusive" than *That's it* or *That's all [there is to it]*. There's no connection with *how it all started* unless it so happens that what was previously being discussed was the *origin* of something. The same construction can equally well appear as *There **we** have it*, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every example it has the meaning of something been done/happening/occurring not for the first time. Maybe even as the summary of a longer statement, as mentioned in a comment above.

> - **1., 2. and 3.** Here something happened that did occur once or more often before. It is just a repeated behavior or thought or practice or event.
>
> *Like it happened before, ...*
>
> - **4.** Here you are presented the news again, since maybe you missed the important beforehand.
>
> *I give you another opportunity to read the news.*

---

A 'little' differently written:

> **1. And once more someone assumes the existence of something like a God without any reason or proof and hints, that anyone who suggest this could be wrong, will face the consequences fit for a heretic.**
>
> **2. For the second time he cannot cope with his feelings for her, since they overwhelm him. He might not suffer loosing her a third time and pretends not to have feelings so there would be no loss.**
>
> **3. After the last incidence with this company in our city, again they polluted a river in the suburb.**
>
> **4. I tossed you the newspaper, since you seem to have missed the election results reading at breakfast.**

Comment: Thank you so much! I now understand all of the examples. That's a diligent answer.